# Android getActivity() is undefined

Tags: android

I have errors in my class MainActivity.

**The error:** `The method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
    PlaceSlidesFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;

    public static final String TAG = "detailsFragment";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,
                container, false);

        mAdapter = new PlaceSlidesFragmentAdapter(getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        ((CirclePageIndicator) mIndicator).setSnap(true);

        mIndicator
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getActivity(),
                                "Changed to page " + position,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                            float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                    }
                });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use getActivity() method in fragments only, to get context in activity class use this keyword

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is because you're using `getActivity()` inside an inner class. Try using:

`SherlockFragmentActivity.this.getActivity()`

instead, though there's really no need for the `getActivity()` part. In your case, 
`SherlockFragmentActivity .this` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. Now I have other problem but is another topic.

Comment: hey i used your answer but i got :
No enclosing instance of the type SherlockFragmentActivity is accessible in scope
it's inside an asynctask, any suggetsions?

Comment: @user1654206 you know that the `SherlockFragmentActivity` is the name of the class. If you are unsure about your class name check the top of your file under the import declarations

Answer (score 29):

If you want to call your activity, just use **this** . You use the getActivity method when you are inside a fragment.

Answer (score 7):

You want `getActivity()` inside your class. It's better to use

```
yourclassname.this.getActivity()
```

Try this. It's helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, it was enough to use:

myclassname.this