# Cannot resolve symbol OuterClass, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access the top-level activity (MainActivity) from within the ResultCallback interface using `OuterClass.this` but the error says:

> cannot resolve symbol OuterClass

I am using the sample code from SettingsApi in the docs for Google APIs for Android.

Also, I get another error saying:

> cannot resolve symbol REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ...
   ...
   protected void createLocationRequest() {
      ...
      ...
      result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() { 
         @Override
         public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
           final Status status = result.getStatus();
           final LocationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
           switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS: 
               ...
               break;
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED: 
               try {
                  status.startResolutionForResult(
                      OuterClass.this,
                      REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
               } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                   ...
               }
               break;
             case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
               ...
               break;
           }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution: instead of using `OuterClass.this`, I used `MainActivity.this` and it works!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS is just a local integer of the value 1.

[Here's a link](https://gist.github.com/simformsolutions/d0243efb151214ffe0785432d402bd7e) to a github example that declares the following:

```
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
```

And then uses it in call to the same function as your code later on:

```
case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:    
  ...    
status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
```

This question has been asked previously on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572323/what-is-the-value-of-request-check-settings).

I can certainly understand the confusion.

REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS is used in an example within [Google Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) without ever explaining what that value was or meant.

Even in the [documentation specifically about Status.startResolutionForResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Status.html#startResolutionForResult(android.app.Activity,%20int)) it describes the parameter as: "The request code to pass to onActivityResult."

Comment: what does 0x1 mean?

Comment: The 0x prefix in "0x1" indicates that everything to the right of "0x" is hexadecimal (base-16) number (e.g. 0x1A is Hex for the number 26).  The number 1 is identical, regardless the base.

Comment: I'm not certain on the getActivity().  I'm not much of an Android expert.  I do see a similar [StackOverflow] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705973/android-getactivity-is-undefined) topic, however.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I later got the solution, check below

Answer (score 0):

I answered it here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48428074/9263399

The google doc is pretty confusing since it uses a placeholder as if it's a predefined dialog type code.